# Whats the difference between AJAX ans JSX?

Tags: javascript

## What is the difference between AJAX and JSX ##
Why **JSX** not **AJAX**, cause according to my knowledge both are use for the same purpose.

Comment: Are you sure they are used for the same purpose?

Comment: both are used to divide page in to components instead of refreshing the whole page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is JSX?

JSX is a statically-typed, object-oriented programming language designed to run on modern web browsers.

JSX performs optimization while compiling the source code to JavaScript.

In contrast to JavaScript, JSX is statically-typed and mostly type-safe. The quality of applications becomes higher when being developed using JSX, since many errors will be caught during the compilation process.

You can use JSX while developing a ReactJS app e.g.

Basically JSX is a language that compiles to JavaScript.

---

---

What is AJAX?
AJAX = Asynchronous JavaScript And XML.

AJAX is not a programming language.

AJAX just uses a combination of:

- A browser built-in XMLHttpRequest object (to request data from a web
  server)
- JavaScript and HTML DOM (to display or use the data)

AJAX allows web pages to be updated asynchronously by exchanging data with a web server behind the scenes. This means that it is possible to update parts of a web page, without reloading the whole page.

Basically AJAX allows you to update certain parts of your page without refresh of the whole page.